# Can PN532 RFID used as a dynamic tag?

Tags: nfc, rfid

I have a use case where a device with NFC setup should act as tag and that tag configuration would be different every time with different URL mapped to the tag.

For example, the device tag will have URL1 mapped to the tag and anyone tapping on the tag will read URL1. Later, the same tag will have the mapping to URL2 and anyone tapping on tag will read URL2.

Would PN532 be a good solution for this? Or should I consider any other components along with PN532 or without PN532?

Appreciate any help.